# Data not updating in ChildViewController when pop to ParentViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have a `ParentViewController` in which I am using a other `ChildViewController`'s view by this code in `ViewDidLoad`

```
 UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    _childVC = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ChildViewController"];

    [self addChildViewController:_childVC];
    [self.myView addSubview:_childVC.view];
    [_childVC didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

Now there is an tableView in ChildVC which have data from a dataArray , when parent view controller call for first time it works fine, and show right data in self.myView but when I push to a another view controller which results in updating the dataArray of tableView of the child view controller. Now when I  pop to parent view from that other VC the  tableview data in self.myView did not get updated.

I tried this in ParentView

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    [_childVC didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}
```

And this in child view controller

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

And I did not add any code in ChildVC related to ParentVC.
Don't care about why and how data is updating, just pretend it is updating whenever I push to other view controller from parent view controller.

Comment: You have not provided enough information. You talk about data being updated, but don't tell us anything about that data or how it's shared between view controllers. It's also not clear what you mean by "... when I pop to parent view from any other VC the data in childView did not get updated." What do you mean pop to parent view? You mean if you push a new view controller on top of the current view controller that contains the child view controller, and then later pop that new view controller off to re-expose the parent view controller who's code you've posted?

Comment: You need to present a clear and complete picture of the problem you're trying to solve or we won't be able to help.

Comment: The data should be updated because the dataArray in child view controller' s table view is getting updated when I push parent view controller to a other view controller. And you are right about the pop to parent view thing. So the problem is 'myView' which have a subview of child view controller's view is not showing updated tableview.

Comment: That doesn't really help.You haven't addressed ANY of the issues I raised.

Comment: What would cause your child view controller's table view to update itself? You need to somehow send it a reloadData message if you want it to update it's contents.

Comment: -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
   [self.tableView reloadData];} I did this for data reloading in Child view controller.

Comment: I suspect that the viewWillAppear method doesn't get called when a parent view controller gets covered and then re-exposed. Set a breakpoint in viewWillAppear and see if it's getting called. (And please update your original question and add the additional information. It's very hard for other readers of this thread to read your vague question, then slog through a bunch of comments in order to understand the problem.

Comment: Yes the problem is  viewWillAppear of child view controller is not getting called. And I updated the answer hope it is enough to understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your child view controller's viewWillAppear method won't be called when the parent gets covered by a push and then revealed when that view controller is popped.

You will need to build some mechanism for notifying the child view controller that it's data has changed.

Here are a couple of possibilities:

You could create a notification manager notification that you broadcast when the data changes, and listen for that notification in your child view controller.

You could set up a protocol that lets the parent view controller notify the child when the parent is about to appear, and use that to ask the child to reload it's table view.